# How to clean up anaconda base environment?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, miniconda

I have just reinstalled Miniconda. After that I ran `pip list` in base environment. The output is following:

```
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
brotlipy               0.7.0
certifi                2021.10.8
cffi                   1.15.0
charset-normalizer     2.0.4
colorama               0.4.4
conda                  4.12.0
conda-content-trust    0+unknown
conda-package-handling 1.8.1
cryptography           36.0.0
idna                   3.3
menuinst               1.4.18
pip                    21.2.4
pycosat                0.6.3
pycparser              2.21
pyOpenSSL              22.0.0
PySocks                1.7.1
pywin32                302
requests               2.27.1
ruamel-yaml-conda      0.15.100
setuptools             61.2.0
six                    1.16.0
tqdm                   4.63.0
urllib3                1.26.8
wheel                  0.37.1
win-inet-pton          1.1.0
wincertstore           0.2
```

But the fact is that I did not install them. How packages like `tqdm, colorama, brotlipy, cryptography` and others appeared here? It supposed to be an empty base environment. Your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

i would do:

```
conda clean -a -d
#-d = dryrun
```

and if that's okay with me

```
conda clean -a -y
#-y = yes (no promt)
```

Answer (score -2):

Do:

```
conda uninstall -n base --all
```

Comment: Good day! Thanks for response, but It does not work with base environment

Comment: Alright. How about conda install --name base --revision 0? 
It should roll back to the first change done in the base env.